# What does "lock up the longhairs" mean in anti Vietnam war 1968 protest context?

Tags: meaning

What does "lock up the longhairs" mean in anti Vietnam war 1968 protest context?

Context: The Chicago Seven, a group of anti–Vietnam War protesters charged with conspiracy and crossing state lines with the intention of inciting riots at the 1968 Democratic National Convention in Chicago.

Comment: Can you please provide the whole sentence which uses this phrase?

Comment: The young people who took part in such protests were often 'hippy' types with long hair.

Comment: Please see [**longhair**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/longhair). Supporters of the war wanted the demonstrators to be jailed, and they hated hippies anyway. So "lock up the longhairs" could have meant "lock up **all** the hippies", not just those protesters.